# Need help with designing this image

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I create this image or extract it, I guess, in Adobe Illustrator?

[image: Effect that I am after]

Comment: Look at using Illustrators blend tool.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an old style Spirograph image. So yes I would say Illustrator would be the best to use - There is a very good tutorial on line here http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-vector-spirograph-designs--vector-1140 to get you started.